# Magento 2 - What should repository methods return?

Tags: model, resource-model, repository

This question has been on my mind for some time. I'm currently writing a repository with the usual methods: save, getById, getList, delete and deleteById. What is the correct return for each method?

```
Repository::save($dto) 
- should the method return **$this**, **$dto** or (true || false)?
```

```
Repository::getById(int $id)
- for this one I'm pretty sure that it should return the corresponding DTO
```

```
Repository::getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria) 
- should the method (always) return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults $searchResult
```

```
Repository::delete($dto) 
- should the method return **$this** or (true or false)?
```

```
Repository::deleteById(int $id) 
- should the method return **$this** or (true or false)?
```

Comment: Can you please mention here repository class?

Comment: I do not have a specific Repository or DTO class in mind. With this question I'm just looking for general advice (or best practices) when implementing a CRUD functionality for a new custom entity.

Comment: Why not void for delete, and save? If something wrong happen, an exception is raised (couldnotdeleteexceptio and couodnotsavecexception)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the first three you've got correct.

Although clarifying save. This should be false on failure.

For me delete & deletebyid should return a true / false depending on result.